Damage multiplier will not work on "BaseDamage"
Here is the code:
--Esentials
local tool = script.Parent
repeat wait() until tool.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(tool.Parent)
local animator = tool.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid").Animator

local dmgM = player.PlayerGui.Stats.DamageMultiplier.DMGmultiplier.Value
local dmgMT = player.PlayerGui.Stats.DamageMultiplier

tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    holding = true
    if combo == 0 then
        idle:Stop()
        hold1:Play()
        dmgMT.Visible = true
        repeat
            dmgM += 0.01
            dmgMT.Text = "x"..math.clamp(dmgM, 1, 2)
            wait(0.01)
        until holding == false or dmgM == 2
    elseif combo == 1 then
        idle:Stop()
        hold2:Play()
        dmgMT.Visible = true
        repeat
            dmgM += 0.01
            dmgMT.Text = "x"..math.clamp(dmgM, 1, 2)
            wait(0.01)
        until holding == false or dmgM == 2
    end
end)

tool.Deactivated:Connect(function()
    holding = false
    hold1:Stop()
    hold2:Stop()
    if combo == 0 and holding == false then
        dmgMT.Visible = false
        dmgM = 1
        tool.Enabled = false
        tool.Hitbox.CanTouch = true
        wait(0.3)
        idle:Play()
        tool.Enabled = true
        tool.Hitbox.CanTouch = false
        combo += 1
    elseif combo == 1 and holding == false then
        dmgMT.Visible = false
        dmgM = 1
        tool.Enabled = false
        tool.Hitbox.CanTouch = true
        wait(0.5)
        idle:Play()
        tool.Enabled = true
        tool.Hitbox.CanTouch = false
    end
end)

tool.Hitbox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        local tgrPlayer = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        if not tgrPlayer then
            local hum = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
            local humRP = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
            humRP.AssemblyLinearVelocity = Vector3.new(50, 25, 0)
            tool.Handle.Hit:Play()
            local total = baseDMG * dmgM
            hum:TakeDamage(total)
            print(total)
            tool.Hitbox.CanTouch = false
        elseif tgrPlayer then
            return end
    end
end)

I tried making it where when the player charges the tool up for a specific amount of time, the damage output will be multiplied to the base damage.
For example: When I charge the tool until it hits the maximum, the base damage will be multiplied by the damage multiplier.
I tried doing "Humanoid:TakeDamage(total)" as you can see in the piece of code and tried printing the damage output. It was only printing the base damage, and not the total damage. How do I fix this?

Could you shorten your code to be the minimal reproducible example. Your code is long which makes it hard to pinpoint problems.

Does this work?

@skisp It still seems like there's a lot of redundant code. Do your best to reduce it to the absolute minimum needed to reproduce your problem. That may mean rewriting your code from the ground up, which is frustrating but ultimately helpful.
